# how to show loading img inside img till ajax request

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to show loading gif inside a image,
I am retrieving image and values from the database, image will be shown in img control and values will be shown in textbox,I want till the image is retrive from the database i want to show loading gif in the same control where the retrive img from database will be shown .and after the img from the database in fully loaded in img control then the values should be display in text box.

i did some thing like this.

```
 $('#imgAssetCard').load(function () {
  }).attr('src', "../images/loading.gif");


var ImagePath = "GetImageHandler.ashx?param=" + date + "&assetDesc=true&Opt=AssetDesc&Invid=" + Invid + "";


 $('#imgAssetCard').load(function () {
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AjaxGetAssetTagNumAssetDesc.aspx?param=" + date + "&Invid=" + Invid + "",
            async: false,

            success: function (strData) {
                response = strData;

                if (strData != "") {
 }


        });

    }).attr('src', ImagePath);
```

Comment: `GetImageHandler.ashx` gives you the actual image `src`? You want to show the image and the text from the AJAX call when both are done, and until that you want to show the loading gif?

Comment: i want first, image should be retrive from database through getImageHandler.ashx till the image are retriving ,loading gif should be shown in the same object where image from database is going to be displayed,once the images from the database get display  then data (text) should be displayed,through ajax request

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this for this purpose:

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#divOverlay').css('display', 'block');
     }).ajaxStop(function () {
         $('#divOverlay').css('display', 'none');
    });
```

where the html is this:

```
    <div id="divOverlay" style="top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 20000; width: 100%; height: 100%; cursor: wait; display: none;">
        <div class="container">
            <img alt="loading" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" style="height: 22px; left: 12px; padding-top: 139px; position: absolute;" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Obviously, to use this you need to modify this piece of code, but you get the logic from here.

**Update:**
I did not understand what you want at the first time.

```
$('#imgAssetCard').attr('src', "../images/loading.gif");
var ImagePath = "GetImageHandler.ashx?param=" + date + "&assetDesc=true&Opt=AssetDesc&Invid=" + Invid + "";
var $Img = $("<img/>").attr("src", ImagePath).load(function () {
    $('#imgAssetCard').attr('src', $Img.attr('src'));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AjaxGetAssetTagNumAssetDesc.aspx?param=" + date + "&Invid=" + Invid + "",
        async: false,
        success: function (strData) {
            response = strData;
            if (strData) { }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i am getting from database using generic handler how will i use ajaxstart and stop ,please give some demo

Comment: @user2522779 `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` are global, the code snippet here will display the loading gif anytime there is an AJAX request.

Comment: @user2522779 I asked some questions in a comment to your question.